# How does the DocuSign reminder feature work?

Tags: docusignapi

1. Reminders enabled for the DocuSign template
2. Set the reminder email to start 4 days after I sent it to the signer
3. Set the frequency to every day

My question is how does this work with a signing order? For example:

There are 3 recipients in the signing order: User A (1st), User B (2nd), User C(3rd/last)
We sent the envelope on 3/01/2016, the reminder will start on 3/5/2016 and continue everyday.

1. "User A" gets the envelope first in the signing order and signs it on 3/3/2016.
2. "User B" gets the envelope on 3/3/2016, will "User B" be sent a reminder on 3/5/2016? Or will it be on 3/7/2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to cast my answer as "3/5/2016". The 'set reminder email to start X days' should be calculated based on when the envelope was SENT out to the door/first recipient(s). These settings should represent reminders based on the entire transaction, not re-calculated on a per recipient level.

Comment: As an update, IF you re-send the envelope using the web app or API, the reminder frequency is re-calculated based off that re-send date.